# Chrome Browser Developer Tools: Scripts Show Up Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome

When using Chrome's Developer Tools to debug Javascript, the list of 'Scripts' tends to add multiple occurrences of each script as I'm changing/reload/testing the code.  Safari uses the same essential tool set and does not do this.  It's not unknown for a script to show up in this list 10 times.  When this happens, the only thing I can think to do is to kill the tab and reload it.  Is this a known bug?

Chrome version 18.0.1025.168 (up to date as of this writing)

Mac OSX version 10.7.3 (Lion)

Cheers!

Mark

Comment: I'm seeing this as well: `Windows 7, Chrome 19.0.1084.52`, doesn't happened in Firebug. _Going to install and check Webkit debugger in Safari for Windows now._

Comment: Thanks for the corroboration.  I've used both Firebug and the WebKit debugger in Safari (Mac) for the same code and don't see this problem in either.  I hate to switch browsers for testing code but I may if this persists.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It's pretty annoying to have to guess at which script is the right one, the one with actual code in it, when debugging...

Comment: Here's the issue on the Chromium project: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=115543 Following the steps there I could not reproduce (Chrome 20.0.1132.57, OSX 10.6.8), but I was experiencing this bug last night.

Comment: Do you have a sample page where you consistently see this happening?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using Chrome extensions. Some extensions will cause this issue, check by  disable some of them.

Comment: Disabled all extensions, restarted, even ran it in incognito mode and still have multiples popping up... :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this could be a bug. See:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113490

You could try seeing if there are several frames that are using the same script and test the frames one at a time...

Comment: I just checked this out too. There is only one frame on the page... Thanks for the input though. I was hopeful on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that the scripts are not being called in your source multiple times. It's been my experience that I include js files multiple times on accident and didn't realize it until inspecting the final source HTML in Chrome's Developer Tools.